# Deducing PHP Closure parameters

Tags: php, closures

Is there any chance that I can deduce PHP Closure parameters type information? Consider this example:

```
<?php

$foo = function(array $args)
{
    echo $args['a'] . ' ' . $args['b'];
};

$bar = function($a, $b)
{
    echo $a . ' ' . $b;
};

$closure = /* some condition */ $foo : $bar;

if(/* $closure accepts array? */)
{
    call_user_func($closure, ['a' => 5, 'b' => 10]);
}
else
{
    call_user_func($closure, 5, 10);
}

?>
```

I want to leave some freedom for user so he or she could decide which way is better to define a Closure that will be registered in my dispatcher - will it accept parameters in associative array or directly as Closure parameters. So, dispatcher need to deduce parameters of the passed Closure to determine which way should it call this Closure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`reflection`](http://php.net/reflection), if you need to make decisions, based on code structure. In your case [`ReflectionFunction`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php) and [`ReflectionParameter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionparameter.php) are your friends.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$func = function($a, $b){ echo implode(' ', func_get_args()); };

$closure    = $func;
$reflection = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
$arguments  = $reflection->getParameters();

if($arguments && $arguments[0]->isArray()){
    echo 'Giving array. Result: ';
    call_user_func($closure, ['a' => 5, 'b' => 10]);
} else {
    echo 'Giving individuals. Result: ';
    call_user_func($closure, 5, 10);
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Giving individuals. Result: 5 10
```

Change definition to test:

```
$func = function(array $a){ echo implode(' ', $a); };
```

Output:

```
Giving array. Result: 5 10
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thank you, I didn't know that PHP has reflection :)

Comment: Is there any special reason to do `$closure = &$func;`? before reflecting the closure?

Comment: @tonix nope, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier to have your function be able to accept different types of input.

For instance, in this case:

```
$foo = function() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    if( is_array($args[0])) $args = $args[0];
    echo $args[0]." ".$args[1];
}
```

Comment: Yea, I know, but this will make things uncomfortable for my users who write their Closures. My goal is to get rid of any type of requirements, to let the user implement his Closure without any special knowledge about the way of implementation.