# Get parameter passed to __call instance method( new Reflecction() ?)

Tags: php, reflection

**General information**

- I have a class that has an instance.
- This instance has a __call magicc method defined
- The magic method __call() defines the request method the instance will respond to.
- The php version used is 5.5.

**What i would like to achieve**

- The magic method __call() defines the request method the instance will respond to.
- $request[0] is the regex to respond to and $request[1] the closure.
- I want to define a prefix instance method.
- First parameter of the prefix method is the stringto prepend to $request[0].
- The second argument is an array of instance methods that use __call().

The magic __call() method if the instance :

```
public function __call($method, $request) {

    $this->_links[strtoupper($method)] [$this->_baseUrl . $request[0]] = $request[1];

    return $this;
}
```

The prefix method as it is now  ;

```
public function prefix($prefix, $callbackmethods = array()) {

        foreach ($callbackmethods as $closure) {
                $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

**Example of code structure i am trying to achieve.**

```
# Normal method call to __call
$link->get('/', function(){

});


# Prefic the regex of multiple method calls to __call
$link->prefix('/admin', [
    $link->get('user/(\d+)', function(){

    }),
    $link->post('user/(\d+)', function(){

    }),
    ]);
```

**What i have tried**

- Looked at stack overflow questions and found the Php Reflection class ([Deducing PHP Closure parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198804/deducing-php-closure-parameters))
- After finding that i tried to test various combination of the class. All my attempts ended in incorrect output.
- The php manual page i have been researching and using : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

What i want to achieve is to define a public function prefix($prefix, $callbackmethods = array()). This way the user can easlily prepend a string to the regex to be matched.

Is the reflection class the right way? 
Am i looking for the wrong thing? 
Can this be achieved with Php. 
Are there other options?
Can anyone show me how to use this correctly, if the reflection class is the right way?

This is a learning project for me so please don't advice to use an existing routing class.

**Update**

I have resolved the problem differently with the following code.After that code the filtering is done inside the __call() method. See the answer provided below for a more elegant solution.

```
  /**
*
* @param type $prefix
* @param type $requestMethod
* @return \Link
*/
    public function prefix($prefix, $requestMethod = false) {

        $this->_applyPrefix = true;

        if ($requestMethod != false) {

            $this->_prefixMethod = strtoupper($requestMethod);
        }

        $this->_prefix = $prefix;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
*
* @return \Link
*/
    public function end() {

        $this->_applyPrefix = false;

        $this->_prefixMethod = false;

        $this->_prefix = false;

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this setup is that the `__call()` method itself will add a route to the list of routes. So wrapping those calls within a call to `prefix()` doesn't change that, the `__call()` will still be executed first.

So it has nothing to do with how anonymous functions / closures work, the problem is the order of execution.

I suggest you choose a slightly different approach:

- Create a class that will represent a single route (`Route`). You can manage it more easily this way.
- Have the `__call()` method create and return a Route object, but don't have it add the route to the list.
- Have the `prefix()` method create new `Route` objects based on the routes you pass to it.
- Implement a separate `add()` that will add the route to the list.

This could look something like this:

```
class Router
{
    /**
     * @type array
     */
    private $routes = array();

    /**
     * @param Route|Route[] $routes
     */
    public function add($routes)
    {
        foreach ((array)$routes as $route) {
            $this->routes[] = $route;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param  string  $prefix
     * @param  Route[] $routes
     * @return Route[]
     */
    public function prefix($prefix, array $routes)
    {
        $prefixedRoutes = array();

        foreach ($routes as $route) {
            $prefixedRoutes[] = new Route(
                $route->getMethod(),
                $prefix . $route->getUri(),
                $route->getController()
            );
        }

        return $prefixedRoutes;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string $name
     * @param  array  $arguments
     * @return Route
     */
    public function __call($name, array $arguments)
    {
        $method     = $name;
        $uri        = $arguments[0];
        $controller = $arguments[1];

        return new Route($method, $uri, $controller);
    }
}

class Route
{
    /**
     * $var string
     */
    private $method;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $uri;

    /**
     * @var callable
     */
    private $controller;

    /**
     * @param string   $method
     * @param string   $uri
     * @param callable $controller
     */
    public function __construct($method, $uri, $controller)
    {
        $this->method     = $method;
        $this->uri        = $uri;
        $this->controller = $controller;
    }

    /**
     * @param  string $prefix
     */
    public function prefix($prefix)
    {
        $this->uri = $prefix . $this->uri;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMethod()
    {
        return $this->method;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUri()
    {
        return $this->uri;
    }

    /**
     * @return callable
     */
    public function getController()
    {
        return $this->controller;
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
$router->add(
    $router->get('/', function() {
        // ...
    });
);

$router->add(
    $router->prefix('/blog', array(
        $router->get('/(\d+)', function() {
            // ...
        }),
        $router->post('/(\d+)', function() {
            // ...
        })
    ))
);
```

Now this is a very, very simple setup. And it could be solved a lot more elegantly.

I strongly suggest you take a look at [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) (which is a micro-framework based on [Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) components). It has a router that looks *a lot* like what you're trying to achieve. You could take inspiration from [that code](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This helps me a lot! I will study the Silex source to learn how they approach things. I have continued studying SPL. All is very educational coming from a Ruby background. I will award the bounty shortly.

Comment: I have added another solution to my question. For this study project i want to keep it as simple as possible and not go beyond my knowledge. You answer is much appreciated and will be studied and rewarded with the bounty.