# Type-hint closure parameters

Tags: php, closures, type-hinting

With type-hinting in PHP is it possible to type-hint the parameters of a closure?

for example

```php
function some_function(\Closure<int> $closure) {
    $closure(3);
}

// This would throw an exception
some_function(function(string $value) {
    echo $value;
});

// This would work.
some_function(function(int $value) {
    echo $value;
});
```

Comment: Nope, that's not possible.

Comment: We wish :)  scripting languages don't support it.

Comment: _"scripting languages don't support it"_ - Have you checked _all_ scripting languages?

Comment: :'( GUESS I'M WRITING THIS IN JAVA THEN.

Comment: If strict typing all around is super important for you, PHP won't be a good fit. Yes, it has come a long way since PHP 5, but it's still not even close to being as strict as many other typed languages (and will probably never be that, at least not as strict as Java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively. You would need to manually make use of [reflection](https://php.net/reflection).

```
<?php
function some_function(\Closure $closure) {

    $reflection = new ReflectionFunction($closure);
    $parameters = $reflection->getParameters();
    if(!isset($parameters[0]))
    {
        // I'm lazy but you should program this to throw a fatal exception
        echo 'some_function() expects parameter one\'s closure to expect at least one parameter'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    elseif($parameters[0]->getType().'' !== 'int') // I'm sure there is a more elegant way to achieve this...
    {
        // I'm lazy but you should program this to throw a fatal exception
        echo 'closure\'s first param should be an int'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else
    {
        $closure(3);
    }
}

// Does not throw an exception
some_function(function(int $value) {
    var_dump($value);
});

// This throws an exception
some_function(function() {
    var_dump($value);
});

// This throws an exception
some_function(function(string $value) {
    var_dump($value);
});
```

Produces:

```
int(3)
some_function() expects parameter one's closure to expect at least one parameter
closure's first param should be an int
```

Also see [Deducing PHP Closure parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19198804/2191572)

Comment: This isn't exactly what i'm looking for. This would require that the parameter passed to the closure match the closure that's given, not require that the closure provided to `some_function` have a parameter of X type. This results in the error message not being very clear compared to what I want the person implementing this code to actually be doing.

Comment: @NathanF. Oh I see. I don't think PHP supports that. Sorry for the misinterpretation.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I think reflection is the only real way to accomplish this.

Comment: @NathanF. At the moment, yes. Given how this is achievable in "user code" I would imagine that PHP could build it into the core at a later date. I would imagine you could write a generic function which can be used to automatically enforce these typehints. You could also propose an [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/howto) and make PHP a better place for all :)

Comment: @NathanF.I am curious to know whether you chose to proceed with PHP or ended up using Java per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56809237/type-hint-closure-parameters/56811963#comment100173046_56809237)